# show 100% width child within non 100% width parent

Tags: html, css, width

I have a div that has max-width of let's say 1024px and I have it's child that needs to take 100% width starting at the left of the screen.

Is it possible without introducing additional markup? I understand that can make child 100% with width: 100vw; but can't seem to push it to the left.

CODE

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle content</a>
  <div class="child">Content</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgbPJj

Comment: These are 2 different things. 100vw will use 100% of the viewport width whilst 100% will use 100% of the parent's width.

Comment: you have set the width of parent to 800px and margin left and right to auto which obviously align the parent to center of its parent (body in this case). and making the child element's width to 100% will fill the parent width..

Comment: Your child div shouldn't exceed the parent div.

Comment: you can do that if you position the child absolute relative to a full page width element like body

Answer (score 3):

This works.

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: grey;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Oh that's what he meant. Cool solution. Anyone using this just be aware that this will cause the `.parent`s height to collapse, and it won't work in 1E8 (like anyone cares) ;)

Comment: @WizardCoder you're right, it doesn't work if there is content below

Comment: @Runnick can you post full code of the whole page with content so we can have another bash at it for you?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible without introducing additional markup? I understand that can make child 100% with width: 100vw; but can't seem to push it to the left.

What do you want to push to the left? The child element? If so, the parent has margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto (shorthand margin: 0 auto). With that you are centering the parent element, hence the child element goes with it.

You might wanna use `margin: 0;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with absolute positioned pseudo elements. I had to add a wrapper with overflow hidden, otherwise a horizontal scroll was added. Someone might be able to figure out how to do it with the wrapper.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXjzjE

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-top:40px;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position:relative;
}

.child:before, .child:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:grey;
}
.child:before {
  left:-100%;
}
.child:after {
  right:-100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">

   <a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle content</a>

   <div class="child">Content</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's probably easier to introduce wrapper on parent link, and make parent  itself 100%. I appreciate your answer though, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Adding the wrapper makes my solution a bit redundant.